# pull url tag from data data array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pull the URL link out from the data structure, i do not know if i have it structured correctly, i am using it in my react-native application.

i have figured it out thank you.

Comment: It will be helpful if you could create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case i think `data[0].data[0].attributes.url` should do the job.

Comment: i get cant not read property 0 of undefined @Snirka

Comment: If you won't provide any code or an example that is similar to your problem it will be hard for me to know what to do. Which `data` you cannot read and get this error? try using `console.log()` to see what you can access and what not , for example first `console.log(data)` and see if it is not empty. If not you can try `console.log(data[0].data)` and see if it is not empty and so on.

Comment: i have added my sectionlist above

Comment: Rather than writing _"i have figured it out thank you"_, accept the answer that solved your problem or that was the most helpful in finding your solution by marking it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: item.data[0].data[0].attributes.url

I didn't write this as a comment because I don't have the reputation to do so.

Comment: i get cant not read property 0 of undefined

Comment: instead of console.log(item), try to write console.log(JSON.stringify(item)), and if it's possible remove that parts that you don't want to show and copy the rest here

Comment: i have added my sectionlist above

Comment: try logging the item variable if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

If item is object what you showed above, I think you can indicate url using follow.

```
item.data[0].data[0].attributes.url
```

Comment: i get "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: That's because item has no data. please check the contents of item using console.log(item) and then show me the result.

Comment: i have added my sectionlist above